# backbone form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

when i click on submit button it should call post request on server with input data and it returns json object.
here i struck where to write success ? and how to receive response object ?
and is it right way to call post request on server?
please a

my js file:

```
(function($){
 var Login = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'/login'
  });

 var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    events: {
      'click input#btn_login': 'submit'
    },
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'submit'); // remember: every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

      },

    submit:function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var login=new Login();

    login.save({accesskey:$('#accesskey'),secretekey:$('#secretekey')});
    },    
  });

  var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

html file:

```
<form class="form-signin" id="form_signin">
 <table>
  <tr>                
   <td><label>Accesskey:</label>
    <input type="text" name='accesskey' id="accesskey" class="form-control" placeholder="A
    ccess Key" required autofocus>
      </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
        SecretKey:<input type="text" name='secretekey' id="secretekey" class="form-control" placeholder="Secret key" required autofocus>
         </td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <input class="btn" id="btn_login" type=submit name=submit>
          </td>
       </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ajax jquery function :

```
 submit:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var login=new Login();

         $.ajax({
                url: Login.Model.url,
                data: config.data,
                dataType: config.dataType,
                type: config.type,
                traditional: true,
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response)
                        login.save({accesskey:$('#accesskey'),secretekey:$('#secretekey')});

                },
                error: function (response) {

                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: i want to do form submit in backbone, my code was running using anax call

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better option

```
login.save({
    accesskey:$('#accesskey'),
    secretekey:$('#secretekey')
  }, {
    success : function(model, response, options) {
    },
    error : function(){model, xhr, options} {
    }
  });
```

The backing server method should return OK http status for success and an error status for other scenario.

Comment: i tried this but when i click on submit button it calling get request,